# MS Word Personal Templates

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I'm working with MS Word and am trying to create a list of customized template(s).

i.e. Open Word (2013 / 2016), in the 'New' menu you'll see a list of "Featured" templates, I would like to add my own list of templates.

Through research ([Handy Blog](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/microsoft-word-for-teams/lesson1/all/)), I've learnt that you can create a new template and add it to the "Personal" templates. My problem is, I'd like it to be my own name - instead of Personal, I'd like to have my own heading, say `MyCustomTemplates`.

From some further reading, I've read a few mixed opinions from this and some even saying that it is impossible, as these 'headings' are hard-coded ([Office Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-customize/office-2013-start-screen-tab-for-custom-templates/c00a8f74-dfe1-49d3-8989-8e57efd042a5?auth=1))

Graphical explanation:

[image: Example]

**Doing this manually will be my first step, from there - I'll be adding these templates programmatically.**

Comment: I don't think it's possible, certainly there's no way using the Word object model ("interop"). You can try asking in the IT Pro forum on the Microsoft Technet site if it's possible using a customized set-up (registry entry). But this kind of request has been around for years (even decades) and I've never heard of it being done. Other than that, you could use a Ribbon XML customization to replace the built-in "New" menu and backstage entry with a customized one of your own definition.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for the input. As for your suggestion, are you suggesting a new ribbon item that once clicked would take the user to a "template selection screen" kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help anyone that comes across this - below are my findings (including some really useful forums and feedback) and the solution I am most likely going to go with;

After tons of research I have noted and got confirmation that, to change the name of either of the Word headings (FEATURED, PERSONAL etc.) is not possible - Office have hard coded these - see [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/ms-word-personal-templates/82274bc4-442d-4bf8-b06a-b7702498cbc5?auth=1).

You do have some options though:

- Using the PERSONAL tab within Word, you could create your own
  templates for use (the name would however, remain "PERSONAL") > [This
  URL](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Templates-in-Microsoft-Word)  will take you through the process, step by step.
  If you prefer using a "Support Office URL" - [here it is](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-template-86a1d089-5ae2-4d53-9042-1191bce57deb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
- As suggested by Doug Robbins, in [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/ms-word-personal-templates/82274bc4-442d-4bf8-b06a-b7702498cbc5?auth=1) - you could "***Add the New Document or Template command to the Quick Access Toolbar and create a folder under:
  C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates***". This is not ideal for my implementation.
- Create an Addin Template using [this URL](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html)
- Use the Ribbon XML, (**this is most likely going to be my route**): Create a Ribbon XML for the Word application, the user must select this option (click on your ribbon item), then from a folder that you specify, let the user select a template (that you've added) for them to work with. Load the template to the current word document.

I hope this helps.